# Mysql inserts in stored procedure slow over Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am seeing mysql insert times performing orders of magnitude slower when called over JDBC when compared to calling from an IDE or on the mysql command line and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I am running everything locally, so network latency should not be an issue.

I created the following very contrived example to illustrate the point.

I created a stored procedure that takes in a single INT and inserts it into a table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE testInsert(IN input INT)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If I were to call this procedure from the command line or a mysql IDE (I am using SQLyog):

```
CALL testInsert(0);
```

The procedure call happens, for all intents and purposes, instantly:

```
Execution Time : 0.007 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 0.009 sec
```

However if am to call the procedure from Java, using the following code:

```
public void testStoredProcedureInsert() throws SQLException{
    //custom class for managing the sql and variables on the prepared statement
    SQLStatementBinder sqlBinder = new SQLStatementBinder();
    sqlBinder.appendSql("CALL testInsert(?)");

    //will store the object into a collection in the sql binder
    sqlBinder.addBindVariable(0);

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname", "user", "pass");

    CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall(sqlBinder.getSQL());

    //bindSql loops through bind variables and sets the appropriate parameters based on the type of the objects - in this case only preparedStatement.setInt(1, 0) is called.
    stmt = (CallableStatement)sqlBinder.bindSql(stmt);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    stmt.executeQuery();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("time to call procedure - " + (end-start) + "ms");
}
```

The runtime of the update (note that I am only timing the actual execution so connection overhead and etc are not being taken into account) averages to be about **70ms**.

To even further illustration the point, if I put several inserts in a row into the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE testInsert(IN input INT)
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

        INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
        VALUES(input, input);

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Calling from SQLyog still quite quick:

```
Execution Time : 0.040 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.003 sec
Total Time     : 0.044 sec
---------------------------------------------------
```

Calling the same java code above now averages **225ms** per procedure call.

I am hoping that there is some trivial thing I am doing wrong, but am open to any suggestions or things that I should test. Or is there just that much extra overhead when calling from java?

Sorry for the somewhat long post but I was trying to provide a decent amount of information. Thanks for any help!

**Update** Just an additional situation, if I move the five inserts into a single line:

```
 DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE testInsert(IN input INT)
    BEGIN
            INSERT INTO test_table(column_1, column_2) 
            VALUES(input, input),(input, input),(input, input),(input, input),(input, input);

        END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

The java runtime is averaging **80ms** which shows that each individual statement in the procedure seems to have some extra overhead when being called from java.

Calling other procedures that have no inserts, even those that are more complicated and return several different result sets are taking significantly less time than some simple inserts. Procedures with only selects return very quickly, but add an insert into the procedure though and the runtime is much slower than expected (again, just from java - not from an SQLyog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - after many hours I randomly decided to try to change engine on the table from InnoDB to MyISAM and this seemed to speed up inserts significantly.

Guess I will have to do more review on the differences between the two engines, other than lack of FKs and transactions in MyISAM.

At least it is progress.

Answer (score 1):

try using a JDBC connection pool instead and check the timestamps - it should be lower (though not the same as the MySQL insert).
Also check the data types being used for the insert into MySQL and whether that can be optimized somehow.

Comment: Is the connection pool going to make a big difference on a single call? Do you have a preferred connection pool library or some good examples?

Comment: yes it can - you should compare timestamps before and after getting the connection under normal and heavy loads.  Using a connection pool should do better as load increases based on how you configure the pool and use it.  For one reference, you can look at the connection pool and code used for tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) - there are plenty of other options available (if you are using an application server/servlet container - most come with a connection pool)

Comment: @MrZorn It would be good to read [Connection Pooling](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html). Citing from first statements: "If you have used a SQL or other similar tool to connect to a database and act on the data, you probably know that getting the connection and logging in is the part that takes the most time. An application can easily spend several seconds every time it needs to establish a connection... If you are using a JDBC release prior to 2.0 and want to improve performance, you can cache JDBC connections instead."

Comment: I will look into Connection Pooling - but my Java timings are not starting until after the connection has been created (as far as I can tell at least).

Also - calling other procedures that have no inserts, even those that are more complicated and return several different result sets are taken significantly less time than some simple inserts.